# Kotlin - Type mismatch: inferred type is Any? but Boolean was expected

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying my hands on Kotlin. Being from a Python background is really giving me a tough time to get the knack of the Kotlin syntax. I'm trying to do a simple dictionary (Mutable Map) operation. However, its giving me exceptions.

[This is what I tried. Kotlin compiler](https://pl.kotl.in/y4hcWRJN0)

Adding the code snippet for reference.

```
fun main() {
    val openActivityMap = mutableMapOf<String, MutableMap<String, Any>>()
    val packageName = "amazon"
    val currentTime = 23454321234
    if(openActivityMap.containsKey(packageName)){ 
        if(openActivityMap[packageName]?.get("isAlreadyApplied")){
            if((openActivityMap[packageName]?.get("lastAppliedAt") - currentTime) > 3600){
                openActivityMap[packageName]?.put("isAlreadyApplied", false)
            }
        }
        else{
            openActivityMap[packageName]?.put("isAlreadyApplied", false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that heterogeneous maps are quite rare in Kotlin. I guess the values of your main map shouldn't be maps themselves but instead instances of a class with properly typed properties (like `isAlreadyApplied` and `lastAppliedAt`). Is there a particular reason why you're using a map for those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend writing tests first and working in small increments, but this should fix your compilation issues:

```
fun main() {
    val openActivityMap = mutableMapOf<String, MutableMap<String, Any>>()
    val packageName = "amazon"
    val currentTime = 23454321234
    if(openActivityMap.containsKey(packageName)){ 
        if(openActivityMap[packageName]?.get("isAlreadyApplied") as Boolean){
            if((openActivityMap[packageName]?.get("lastAppliedAt") as Long - currentTime) > 3600){
                openActivityMap[packageName]?.put("isAlreadyApplied", false)
            }
        }
        else {
            openActivityMap[packageName]?.put("isAlreadyApplied", false)
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Also I prefer to avoid nullable variables and mutable objects in general, but I suppose there's an exception to every rule.

Comment: Two questions. 1) When I'm checking `openActivityMap.containsKey(packageName)`, that means it is non-nullable. Any way to improvise on this by not using `?` ??

Comment: 2) Why is `openActivityMap[packageName]["isAlreadyApplied"]` is not accessible? I read for compiler to compile nullable vars, we need to put `?.get`. But since, im sure this wont be the case, can I get rid of `?.get` ?

Comment: In all honesty, I was disappointed not to be able to say ```openActivityMap[packageName]["isAlreadyApplied"]``` myself--I wanted to. Alas, the compiler is prohibiting it and I'm content to know there's a good reason (which I haven't thought much about). I know you're experimenting/learning.. My background is mostly strongly typed languages, so I have certain biases...

Comment: not sure what you mean, `openActivityMap[packageName]!!["lastAppliedAt"]` and `openActivityMap[packageName]?["lastAppliedAt"]` are both there

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast To answer your first question, if you want to get the value anyway, you should first get it and store it to a variable, then use a null check on that instead of using `containsKey` (it will benefit from smart cast). It would be really beneficial to extract `openActivityMap[packageName]` to a variable here anyway, as multiple null-checks would be avoided. Please check out my answer for your second question, or if you want more details.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I'd like to point out another solution here.

As I commented on the OP, heterogeneous maps with fixed string keys like this are usually better expressed with classes in Kotlin. For instance, in your case, the class for your main map's values could be the following:

```kotlin
data class PackageInfo(
    var isAlreadyApplied: Boolean,
    var lastAppliedAt: Long,
)
```

(you could obviously add more properties if need be)

This would save you all the casts on the final values.

Another point I'd like to make is that if you access the value for a key anyway, you don't need to check up front the existence of the key with `containsKey`. Maps return `null` for keys that are not associated with any value (this is why you need to check for null after getting the value).

The compiler cannot see the correlation between `containsKey` and the subsequent `get` or `[]` access. However, it's smart enough to understand a null check if you simply get the value first and then check for null.

This always applies unless you want to tell the difference between keys that aren't in the map and keys that are in the map but associated to null values (which is quite rare).

All in all, I would write something like that:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val openActivityMap = mutableMapOf<String, PackageInfo>()
    val packageName = "amazon"
    val currentTime = 23454321234
    val packageInfo = openActivityMap[packageName]
    if (packageInfo != null) { // the key was found and the value is smart cast to non-null in the next block
        if (packageInfo.isAlreadyApplied) {
            if ((packageInfo.lastAppliedAt - currentTime) > 3600) {
                packageInfo.isAlreadyApplied = false
            }
        } else {
            packageInfo.isAlreadyApplied = false
        }
    }
}

data class PackageInfo(
    var isAlreadyApplied: Boolean,
    var lastAppliedAt: Long,
)
```

Comment: It's not that the compiler isn't smart - it's aware that even if ``containsKey`` returns ``true`` on one line, by the time the ``get`` executes on the next line there's no guarantee that key is still in the map (since it could have been modified by e.g. code running on another thread). It's like a nullable ``var`` basically, you have to treat it the same way - doing a ``get`` and a null check will assign the value to a temporary variable that can't change, so it's safe to work with

Comment: @cactustictacs *It's like a nullable var* - that's not quite correct, all variables are local to the `main` function here. A nullable `var` will be properly smart cast if it's a local variable. The compiler simply doesn't have any facility for contracts that span 2 method calls (the result of `containsKey` cannot affect its evaluation of `get`). That being said, it would be very complex (borderline impossible) to do that even for `Map`, because read-only doesn't mean immutable, so it would require even knowing where the instance comes from (not just the scope of the reference variable)

Comment: I really liked this approach. Clean.

Comment: Yes, this makes things much clearer while avoiding the nullable types!

Comment: @Joffrey yeah I didn't mean to imply it works the same way as a nullable ``var``, just that in a similar way (to a non-local var), the compiler is unable to guarantee it won't be null when it's next accessed. ``Map``s don't provide any concrete assurances about what they'll return (even if the entry hasn't changed) so it's just not possible for the compiler to say it definitely won't be null next time it's accessed

Comment: @cactustictacs True, I guess we kinda agree on what is possible or not then. You're right that it's not only the compiler's fault per-se, because there is no way to improve the compiler to understand this with the existing contract system, even with crazy escape analysis. What I meant by "the compiler is not smart enough" is more general about the contracts and what they can or can't enforce (but I consider contracts to be sort of part of the compiler), I guess "the compiler can't" is probably more appropriate then.

Comment: @Joffrey yeah it's cool, I wasn't sure where you were coming from at first so I just wanted to explicitly point out that there is a reason for it, mostly to help the OP! If you get warnings about being unable to smart cast, there's usually a reason for it - and it's better to grab a temp variable than start throwing ``!!`` around whenever the compiler warns something might be null. We totally agree and "it's not smart enough" is a good way to describe it, I just wanted to make it clear what that means in this context

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just declare your `Map<String, Any>` to return a `Boolean` instead of `Any`?  So,

```
val openActivityMap = mutableMapOf<String, MutableMap<String, Boolean>>()
```

It looks like you're trying to use your second Map to store both Booleans and Ints, which is complicating the logic.  You'll need to typecast if you decide to approach it without Typing.

Comment: What's lastAppliedAt then?

Comment: In need of a new home.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with the 2 statement below

```
if(openActivityMap[packageName]?.get("isAlreadyApplied"))

if((openActivityMap[packageName]?.get("lastAppliedAt") - currentTime) > 3600)
```

As we all know, an IF statement requires a boolean value for it's param. The types of both statement are unknown at compilation time as they are of a Generic type, Any. As such,

1. openActivityMap[packageName]?.get("isAlreadyApplied") could be a null or of type Any (Not Boolean).
2. openActivityMap[packageName]?.get("lastAppliedAt") could be a null or of type Any (an Int was expected here for computation).

This would throw compilation errors as the compiler does not know the types to go with. What could be done is to cast to it's proper types.

Solution

```
openActivityMap[packageName]?.get("isAlreadyApplied") as Boolean ?: false

((openActivityMap[packageName]?.get("lastAppliedAt") as Int ?: 0) - currentTime)
```

Giving a default value if it's null.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try something like this

```
        if (openActivityMap.containsKey(packageName)) {
            val packageMap = openActivityMap[packageName]!!
            val applyRequired = (packageMap["lastAppliedAt"] as Long - currentTime) > 3600
            packageMap["isAlreadyApplied"] = packageMap.containsKey("isAlreadyApplied") && !applyRequired
        }
```

btw. do you really want to have `lastAppliedAt` to be in te future? otherewise it will never be `> 3600`